# Question about reference return type in C++

Tags: c++

I write the following code:

```
const string& combine(string &s1,string &s2)
{
     return s1+s2;
}
```

but when I pass two strings to this function, the result I use "std::cout" to print is the empty string.I don't know what the reason is.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason is that you're returning a reference to an objects that gets destroyed as soon as the function returns. So, your reference is dangling.

Comment: When you evaluate `s1 + s2`, you are creating a new temporary `std::string` object. You return a reference it, but since it is at the end of its life, it is destroyed, so the internal `char *` becomes invalid.

Comment: `s1+s2` is a prvalue. Think of it as a temporary variable that's going out of scope. Using a reference to a variable out-of-scope causes undefined behaviour (anything can happen).

Comment: Can I understand like this: even though s1 and s2 are passed by reference, the sum of them is still a temporary object so that the return value is invalid.

Comment: Yes that pretty much sums it up. Just return it as a non-reference in this case (it won't be too expensive because of return value optimization, there will not be an extra copy, and the string needs to be created anyway to do the + )

Comment: There are plenty of duplicate questions about returning references to temporary objects ... but I'm not sure what the actual question is here. For example, `return s1 += s2;` would work (but it modifies the passed `s1` string) ... because the result is not a temporary object.

Comment: In general you can only return references to objects that have a longer lifetime then the lifetime of the call. Usually member variables

Comment: Beginner's advice for the moment: Don't create a function that returns a reference.

Comment: Thank all of you very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is undefined. This is because `s1 + s2` is an *anonymous temporary* and you are attempting to *bind* that to a reference return type.

The output you observe is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

Changing the return type of the function to a `std::string` *value* is a fix.

Another more interesting fix perhaps is to return one of the input strings modified, so the reference propagates back to the caller. See

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::string& combine(std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
     return s1 += s2;
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "Hello";
    std::cout << combine(s1, ", World!");
}
```

The introduction of `const` allows `", World!"` to bind to `s2`.

---

In general, writing a function that returns a reference can cause unexpected issues. The C++ standard library function `std::max` is a well-known example: if one of the parameters is an anonymous temporary and that value is selected then you have a possibility of a dangling reference! Usually they are confined to returning class member variables (usually bound to a `const` reference).